# Hadoopのサンプルwordcountについて

Tags: hadoop

Hadoopをインストールし、hadoop-mapreduce-examples-x.x.x.jarを使って、
hdfsにwordcountの結果が出力されることを確認しました。

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-x.x.x.jar wordcount /input /output
```

次に自分でjarを作りたく、まずは上記サンプルのWordCount.javaをjarにして、それを実行しようとしています。
サンプルは以下となり、packageだけ変更しました。
WordCount.java

```
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package hadooptest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> [<in>...] <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < otherArgs.length - 1; ++i) {
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[i]));
    }
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,
      new Path(otherArgs[otherArgs.length - 1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

コンパイル実行

```
javac WordCount.java -cp $(/home/hadoop/hadoop-x.x.x/bin/hadoop classpath)
```

実行結果

```
WordCount.class
WordCount$IntSumReducer.class
WordCount$TokenizerMapper.class
```

jar化

```
jar -cf test.jar *.class
```

上記で作成したjarを使ってHadoopコマンドを実行したのですが例外が発生してしまいます。

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar test.jar WordCount /input /output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

※同じような質問でフルパッケージ名にすればよいとあったので、以下を実施したのですが結果は変わらずでした。

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar test.jar hadooptest.WordCount /input /output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hadooptest.WordCount
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

何かアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビルド時にJARに配置されないようにする必要があったようです。
buildのディレクトリを作成しそこにClassファイルが作成されるようにコンパイル後、
build配下で

```
 jar -cvf WordCount.jar .
```

としたjarファイルを指定したところ、正常に実行されました。